# django app creates auth.user and app user at same time and stores auth.user_id in app.user

Tags: django-admin, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I have an app that adds a user to the system via auth.user and the app. On save I want to create the user and then get the auth.user.id and add that to a team_user.id.

I've been trying the code below and getting no where. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Please advise.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SimpleRegForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

        new_teammember = form.save(commit=False)
        new_teammember.team_user = request.user # I know this is not right. 
        new_teammember.save()
```

Comment: Why do you think that's not right?

Comment: Because request.user is null here. The user hasn't been saved yet. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the request.user - It's just user.